# What is the benefit of WSL if windows application cannot run on it?

Tags: linux, windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am a huge fan of Cygwin and when I heard about Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) I immediately installed it.

Sadly, I discovered that beside the fact there is no other terminals than the Windows "bash" console with 16 colors, I also noticed that I cannot execute native windows application on the subsystem such as using Linux Python to connect with an ODBC database or open a DLLs using ctypes.

Thus this very good idea from Microsoft offers no alternative to Cygwin in which Windows `.exe` can be executed.

What would be the benefit of WSL over alternatives such as Cygwin or MinGW?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Not sure it's completely on topic]

I believe the "standard" use case is having a linux development environment inside the windows machine.
While you can get most of the features when using a VM, this solution has much lower overhead